# Adding external module not in NPM or bower using browserify?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to use this starter project:https://github.com/leesei/angular-material-chart-gulp-browserify-boilerplate to kick-off my project but I don't understand why 'angular' is not defined in my current setup.

I'm trying to add this `scrollReveal` module but I can't get it to work. The problem is that when I include this module it causes an error: `angular` is not defined.

`ScrollReveal` has both an angular module and a JS file. I was able to add the main JS file via bower and that seems to be ok. Then at the top of the 'fox-angular-scrollreveal.js' file I added:

```
 var ScrollReveal = require('scrollreveal');
 require('angular');

 module.exports = angular.module('fox.scrollReveal',[]).controller('ScrollRevealCtrl', [
```

It recognizes `ScrollReveal` but causes an error with angular somehow.
In `main.js` I've included the files like this: 

`require('scrollreveal');
require('./vendor/fox-angular-scrollreveal.js');`

and also added `fox.scrollReveal` as a dependency of the main angular module.

I'm not sure what else to try. Can someone please point me in the right direction.